# "Package ufw is not available, but is referred to by another package

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

I was trying to install a firewall in Kali using ufw.This is the issue that keeps coming up. I've tried using

```
apt-get install ufw
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ufw is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kali needs only one line in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` if necessary with `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and save the file.

<sub>**Nano text editor keyboard shortcuts**</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location.</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.</sub>

Install [ufw](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/ufw): ← from kali-rolling repository

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ufw
```

If you want to configure ufw with a friendly GUI application, install gufw with `sudo apt install gufw` .

Comment: but deb isn't working for me that's another issue.

Comment: `/etc/apt/sources.list` in Kali Linux does not need to have more than one single line in it: `deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib` but you can optionally add additional lines to sources.list after that. The first thing you need to do is make sure that your sources.list has no errors in it. Then run the command `sudo apt update` to refresh the list of available software. Finally try to install or remove a package with apt to check if apt is working properly. If you want to configure ufw with a friendly GUI, please install gufw with `sudo apt install gufw`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue; all I did was run the following command

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

What this will do is update and configure all the repositories so that when you run the `sudo apt-get install ufw` command it will install right away! Please reference the following website: https://buildvirtual.net/how-to-update-kali-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is available in their repository.  You could try to run `apt update` to refresh the package index.

Answer (score -1):

I cant comment, whats your /etc/apt/sources.list, i have kali and i can install. Try this `wget  http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/u/ufw/ufw_0.36-6_all.deb  && dpkg -i *.deb && apt --fix-broken install`
And run `apt update` then run the upper command agin as said by
tvanriel. May work.